# Ember, component to redirect

Tags: ember.js, dom-events, ember-cli, gesture

In my ember app I have an `activities` route, with corresponding route, controller and a few components, the template contains:

`{{carousel-activities activities=model}}`

The `carousel-activities` contains:

```
{{#each activities as |activity|}}
    <li>{{carousel-block activity=activity}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```

The `carousel-block` contains some HBS to show the content of each activity:

```
<div class="carousel-block">
  {{#link-to 'activity' activity class="small"}}
    <div class="full-width-image">
      <img src="{{activity.image}}" class="img img-responsive full-width" alt="{{activity.title}}">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>{{activity.title}}</h1>
    </div>
  {{/link-to}}
</div>
```

The block component uses [ember-gestures](https://github.com/runspired/ember-gestures) to monitor the `panDown`, when the event happens the block will redirect the browser to the activity details page.

```
#app/controllers/activities.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

});
```

---

```
#app/components/carousel-activities.js
import RecognizerMixin from 'ember-gestures/mixins/recognizers';
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  Component
} = Ember;

export default Component.extend(RecognizerMixin, {
  recognizers: 'pan',
  panDown() {
    console.log("panDown");
    this.transitionTo('activity', this.get('activity'));
  }
});
```

---

```
#app/components/carousel-block.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
});
```

If I load the activities route, and swipe down on it (raise the panDown event) I get this error in the console:

```
panDown
ember.debug.js:6208 DEPRECATION: Ember.View#transitionTo has been deprecated, it is for internal use only [deprecation id: ember-views.view-transition-to]
        at HANDLERS.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16380:7)
        at raiseOnDeprecation (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16290:12)
        at HANDLERS.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16380:7)
        at invoke (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16396:7)
        at deprecate (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16349:32)
        at Object.deprecate (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26468:37)
        at _emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create.transitionTo (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:52805:24)
        at panDown (http://localhost:4200/assets/myproject.js:261:12)
        at _emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.trigger (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55654:23)
ember.debug.js:42747 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined_emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create._transitionTo @ ember.debug.js:42747_emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create.transitionTo @ ember.debug.js:42736panDown @ carousel-activities.js:24_emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.trigger @ ember.debug.js:45584superWrapper @ ember.debug.js:23209Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:678Backburner.join @ ember.debug.js:702run.join @ ember.debug.js:21280_emberMetalAssign.default.handleEvent @ ember.debug.js:46458exports.default._emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create._Mixin$create.handleEvent @ ember.debug.js:43395exports.default._emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend._bubbleEvent @ ember.debug.js:44482(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:44424jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4737elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4549triggerDomEvent @ hammer.js:2497Manager.emit @ hammer.js:2438emit @ hammer.js:1474Recognizer.emit @ hammer.js:1485inherit.emit @ hammer.js:1764Recognizer.tryEmit @ hammer.js:1502Recognizer.recognize @ hammer.js:1549Manager.recognize @ hammer.js:2314inputHandler @ hammer.js:517MEhandler @ hammer.js:826Input.domHandler @ hammer.js:430
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call transitionTo() from a component. The best way would be to send an action out instead, which will do the transition from the controller.

```
export default Component.extend(RecognizerMixin, {
  recognizers: 'pan',
  panDown() {
    console.log("panDown");
    this.attrs.showDetailsAction(this.get('activity'));
  }
});
```

And then in your controller define the action:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    showDetails(activityData) {
      this.transitionToRoute('activity', activityData);
    }
  }
});
```

And pass the action to your component:

```
{{carousel-block activity=activity showDetailsAction=(action 'showDetails')}}
```

Comment: shouldn't I pass the action also in the template to `carousel-activities` with `{{carousel-activities activities=model showDetailsAction=(action 'showDetails')}}` ??

Comment: Yeah, sorry. So you would do `{{carousel-activities activities=model showDetailsAction=(action 'showDetails')}}` and then `{{carousel-block activity=activity showDetailsAction=attrs.showDetailsAction}}`